# Delete rows with identical ColumnName value in a SQL Table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

I would like to delete all duplicates in the SQL Table that have more than one ID for a single value in ColumnName (or several rows with same ColumnName value).

Here is SQL for delect for one ColumnName values:

```
DELETE FROM MyDataTable WHERE ColumnName = 'UniqueComnName1'
AND ID <> (SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM MyDataTable  WHERE ColumnName = 'UniqueComnName1')
```

I would like to do that for all unique ColumnName in the table (or just simply all ColumnNames in the table). How can I do this?

Comment: what is datatype of ID? Is it comparable? What record do you want to keep in set of record having the same 'UniqueComnName1'?

Comment: If you want to remove the duplicate records based on your `UniqueComnName1`, then use `Row_number() over(partition by UniqueComnName1 order by UniqueComnName1)` and specify deletion for records with `row number`> 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with two little queries:

```
SELECT MIN(ID) AS ID INTO #tmpTable FROM MyDataTable GROUP BY ColumnName
DELETE FROM MyDataTable WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM #tmpTable)
```

Comment: Thanks. I just changes it a bit to this: `DELETE FROM MyDataTable WHERE CID NOT IN ( SELECT MIN(CID) AS CID FROM MyDataTable GROUP BY ColumnName )`

Answer (score 1):

Run this and let me know your result:

```
DELETE FROM MyDataTable
WHERE 
    ID != (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM MyDataTable A  WHERE A.ColumnName = MyDataTable.ColumnName)
```

This query will keep the record that having the ID equals the MAX (id) of records that having the same ColumnName.

Comment: this cannot work. he wants a solution without defining the value of columnname

Comment: @Check my edited query. Simply removed ColumnName = 'UniqueComnName1'

Answer (score 1):

In one Statement this should work:

```
DELETE FROM MyDataTable t
WHERE ColumnName IN (SELECT ColumnName 
            FROM MyDataTable t1 
            WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyDataTable t2 WHERE t1.ColumnName=t2.ColumnName)>1)
        AND ID <> (SELECT TOP 1 ID 
                FROM MyDataTable t3
                WHERE t3.ColumnName = t.ColumnName)
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code is useful to delete duplicate records. The table must have identity column, which will be used to identify the duplicate records. Table in example is has ID as Identity Column and Columns which have duplicate data are DuplicateColumn1, DuplicateColumn2 and DuplicateColumn3.

DELETE
FROM MyDataTable 
WHERE ID NOT IN
(
SELECT MAX(ID)
FROM MyDataTable 
GROUP BY DuplicateColumn1, DuplicateColumn2, DuplicateColumn3)